# How to see where the value is set from Catalog Product details

Tags: product, add

In Admin I can see the property `prodfragrance` dropdown set to few values.

I want to add more attribute to that?

How can i do that where to edit it ?

```
$product->getAttributeText('prodfragrance')
```

> I am brand new to Magento. Please share some lights to this,

Comment: You can admin panel/ store/attributes/product and search 'prodfragrance' in default label.

Comment: thanks , that worked

Comment: if that worked please up my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can admin panel/ store/attributes/product and search 'prodfragrance' in default label.

Now open and add more attribute to that.

I hope it will help you.